# EclEmma Line Number Output Java Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclemma

I installed EclEmma (Code Coverage Eclipse Plugin ) , When I build my code EclEmma Highlights code lines in order to they have been used or not in this running , my question is can EclEmma output the which line number has been executed and which aren't or it can only highlight lines? because I want to compare two large source codes , I need line number outputs. It can count total number of lines that has been executed and it's strange for me that it dosen't output which line numbers!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line numbers are provided in EclEmma (JaCoCo) XML reports. You can create them either by using Ant, Gradle or Maven, or [export](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html) the coverage report data from Eclipse (`File/Export/.../Coverage Report`).